# How do we link a C library like Newlib with a custom linker script?

Tags: c, linker, linker-scripts, newlib, c-standard-library

I'm porting newlib for a manycore architecture being developed in our research group. Up until now, we were writing bare metal code with a minimal crt.S and a linker script. The manycore processor can be programmed using single program multiple data (SPMD) programming model. It requires thread-specific sections to be placed into the region `0x1000-0x2000`. While the rest of the program should be placed after `0x80000000`. How can I handle myriad number of input sections found in default link script with our custom link script?

Or, is there a way to use newlib's default linker script along with our custom script? So that, all contents from `lib*.a` would be linked with newlib's link script and that linked content can be placed after `0x80000000` by the custom script.

Comment: I feel like this is too broad. Just place everything of newlib inside 0x80000000 just like you would any ather normal functions. From a far perspective, newlib is just a bunch or normal functions, like `printf` or `wscanf` etc. Only few need special attention (atexit, signal, etc.) Make sure your `crt.S` calls `__libc_init_array` before `main` and calls `_exit` after `main`, but this is really not needed (if you don't want to support `atexit` and `attribute((constructor))`). Do you plan to use newlib in multithreading mode? I mean, do you plan to use `--enable-newlib-multithread`?

Comment: @KamilCuk Updated the details to make the question more specific! Currently I'm trying to concentrate on porting newlib for single core and run some single core benchmarks. But I would love to learn more about newlib's multithreading features! Are they different from typical reentrant functions?

Comment: Well, in multithreading when you create a new thread, you should just also allocate a new _reent structure for this thread.. See [reent.h](https://github.com/eblot/newlib/blob/master/newlib/libc/include/reent.h#L59). `__getreent()` should return the _reent structure for current thread. Usually newlib is used with `disable-mewlib-multithread` and `enable-newlib-reent-small` as it aims for really small devices. `in default link script` - Can you post examples? Of your link script? Where's newlib "default" link script? Expected output (ex. from objdump). That way you will get help way sooner.